# 25 600 движущихся спрайтов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Постановка задачи: 
Нам нужно создать сетку из спрайтов 160х160. Каждый спрайт движется в рандомном направлении и с рандомной скоростью. При столкновении друг с другом спрайт исчезает и появляется через секунду, где то за экраном.  Нужно что бы это все работало при 30-60 фпс.

Мое решение: 
В скрипте Spawner у меня 3 листа со скоростью, направлением и риджидбоди2д. В старте я создаю спрайты ставлю их по сетку  в двойном цикле, тут же рандомлю скорость и направление и вместе с риджидбоди2д добавляю их в списки. В методе FixedUpdate я прохожу циклом по всем элементам списка риджидбоди2д и даю каждому его  направление и скорость. На спрайте висит скрипт, который отслеживает столкновение через OnTriggerEnter2D и вызывает из Spawner метод,  в котором этот спрайт выключается, перемещается за экран и там снова активируется и продолжает движение. Я смог добиться 20 фпс при 120х120 спрайтах.

Вопрос: Какие методы оптимизаций еще можно применить? 
Ps: Я читал про ECS & Job System помогут ли они мне в этом случае ведь я использую передвижение через риджидбоди, а не трансформ. Если да то не могли бы вы показать на легком примере, как это должно выглядеть.

Спасибо.

Comment: "Какие методы оптимизаций **еще** можно применить"? А какие методы оптимизации вы **уже** реализовали? Судя по описанию, у вас создается 25600 объектов, на которые цепляются 25600 скриптов, слушающих евенты. Это же полный треш.

Comment: по описанию похоже что подойдет использование particleSystem

Comment: Ну изначально у меня в 25600 объектах перемещение осуществлялось в каждом отдельном скрипте в методе Апдейте. Сейчас перемещение происходит в одном Апдейте но по 25600 объектах и это дало прирост производительности. И да у меня на на каждом объекте весит скрипт который слушает ивет при столкновении. В этом и вопрос как можно это оптимизировать.

Comment: На "лёгком примере"? В ECS нет лёгких примеров, по крайней мере сейчас, использовать физику только ради столкновений глупо, все эти столкновения можно просчитывать в тех же jobах. Писать пример не буду, уж извини, не вижу смысла для комьюнити, а просто так тут не биржа для фрилансерских заказов.

Answer (score 2):

1. Все спрайты должны быть в одном атласе. 2. Забыть про использовании физики 2д тел (Для 25тыс тел это чистой воды экстримизм !!!). Но считая всё математически можно сделать лишь хуже, тут нужно быть аккуратным!